# adding a parameter to the mail(... template_name = "something")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I want to send an email with a template called "something" (for example), but I also have a parameter on this page called show_text which is default set to false if undefined. I want to set it to true when I am using the mail function. How do I pass a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this guide, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html. Depending on what version of Rails you are using and how you have your mailer model configured, code examples of passing parameters to mailer methods can look different.  Basically, you pass each parameter as a hash and then access it through instance variables.